# How to get started with ASP.Net MVC 4 / Azure and MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, monodevelop

Has anybody developed an ASP.Net MVC4 Web API project using MonoDevelop? My ultimate goal would be to deploy on Azure. If so, was it easy to set up? Any pitfalls?

I'm a huge fan of ASP.Net MVC 4 and the Azure service, but I'm not letting go of my MacBook Air just yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of would be after you build your project, someone would have to run cspack on a Windows machine.  Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx